# Multiple a list of cells with plus

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I havea long list of cells with percentage data (5%, 10%, 7%, etc.). Now I want to multiple the data with this format:

`A * (1+B2)*(1+B3)*(1+B4)*...`

Is there any shorter formula to do the multiply without writing every cell?

Example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oDVJ4G4F7IyGkbwYjOrvirvjGoKdIvlgqrKipZhQwp4/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=arrayformula(A*product(1+B2:Bn))` where Bn is the last cell to be included.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I have some math before this formula (Ex: 50 * (1+B2)(1+B3)... So I cannot use arrayformual. Is there any alternative?

Comment: You can still use arrayformula even with the additional multiplication: product(1+B2:Bn) is a single value because PRODUCT is an aggregating function so you are calculating A*this value even though it is within an arrayformula expression. The only function operating over an array here is the '+' operator, which is why arrayformula is required.

Comment: Could you please mark the answer as accepted if it meets your requirements?